# Handling relative paths for include files in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing a project in PHP which I am not very familiar. I am using a MVC framework (CodeIgnitor). I have noticed that each time I return a view that resulted from a longer/shorter url string all of my includes break. It appears that the paths are relative to url.

Is $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] the best way to generate include paths in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: why and how are you using includes? It occurred to me I never seem to require this in CI projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base_url() and site_url() is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [User Guide on URL Helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html). It already has all the infos you need and provides with with functions that give you paths for your site.

If you need paths on your file system, there are `BASEPATH`, `APPPATH` and `FCPATH`. Look into `index.php` to see where they point (also has a description of these constants)

Answer (score 0):

I really depends on your application, I don't know how CodeIgnitor works, but here are a few points:

If you use the php path (defined in php.ini) you can always keep you includes in the php path, so including a file is no longer relative to the file path.

If you have a project directory (like /srv/www/myProject/) and all files you are using reside in this dir, then you could define a session value like this $_SESSION['project_path'] = '/srv/www/myProject' and then when including files, it would look like this:

```
include_once($_SESSION['project_path'] . 'included.php');
```

Calling the absolute path would make the include not care about the current path.

Comment: CodeIgnitor has url helper 'base_url()'. This seems to work nicely.