# How can I include files using paths relative to where the file resides?

Tags: php

Imagine I have two directories, **foo** and **bar** in a parent directory, and these directories contain some PHP files:

```
/
/index.php

/foo
/foo/functions.php
/foo/stuff.php

/bar
/bar/doodie.php
```

Let's say:

1. `functions.php` includes `stuff.php`
2. `index.php` includes `functions.php`
3. `doodie.php` includes `functions.php`

Based upon this structure, when `index.php` is run, it will look for `/foo/functions.php`in the `/foo` directory. **However**, `stuff.php` must be included using the relative path according to the location of `index.php`. This works, in the case of when `index.php` is run. **It doesn't work** when `doodie.php` is called because `functions.php` looks for `stuff.php` in the `/foo` directory, which doesn't exist when the location is `/bar`.

Is it possible to include files according to where they reside instead of where they are called from, without using absolute paths (and [session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3243015/613857))?

I apologize if this wasn't clear, it was really tough to describe this...

Comment: It won't let me post for some reason.  JohnP said essentially said everything I would say anyway.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* use absolute paths.

Of course you don't need to include the full path every time. The usual process is that you define a constant called, for example, APP_PATH and set the absolute path of the application in your bootstrap.

After that, whenever you want to include a file, append the APP_PATH constant in your include calls. This will solve your problem.

You could also look at the include_path option, this depends on how your files are located - http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: I understand this solution but where do I store the APP_PATH constant? Will it not create the same issue when called from different places?

Comment: @Ozbekov the only purpose of the **absolute** paths IS to "not create the same issue when called from different places". It is called "absolute" for the reason

Comment: Do you know why PHP doesn't honor the leading slash to make paths relative to the document root? This works for example when posting image urls on a website. `include '/index.php'`

Comment: @mrtsherman PHP honors the file-system.  PHP can and often does access things outside of the document root.

Comment: @mrtsherman because that's the absolute path from the domain as far as the browser is concerned, which is seperate to the webservers file system.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this: 
Create a file in the base folder; in this file define these variables 
define('root', SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); this ensures the root folder is obtained 
define('foo', root . '/foo/'); this defines the path to the foo folder 
define('bar', root . '/bar'); this defines the path to the bar folder 

Now, in whatever file you need to call, include the base file, and you have access to any file in any of those folders. 
So, if you are already in /bar/doodie.php, just include(foo . 'functions.php'), and vice versa. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go the route many MVC goes. It is easy yet reliable. Just redirect all requests to one file in form of index.php?path=database.php (let say bootstrap.php) that is in root directory and then define paths. Here is example of my file that I use in my home made MVC framework.

```
/**
 * BASE_PATH is for server side inclusions.
 * BASE_URL is for client side inclusions (scripts, css files, images etc.) 
 */
define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("BASE_PATH", dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).DS);
define("BASE_URL", dirname(realpath($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])).DS);
define("APP_PATH", BASE_PATH."application".DS);

//$url = $_GET['base_url'];


/**Include core file which loads all necessary files */
require_once (BASE_PATH."core".DS."core.php");
```

and here is core.php (only one line as it have many lines)

```
//Load config files
require_once(BASE_PATH."config".DS."config.general.php");
```